# date command output format

Tags: date, timezone

I have just installed ubuntu server 19.10. When I enter the **date** command I get the following output

> Sun 10 Nov 2019 05:16:05 PM AEDT

My old server running 18.04 gives this output

> Sun Nov 10 17:16:16 AEDT 2019

Note the difference in both the time given and the format.

Can someone advise me where the default format for date output is configured. I can't see anything in the environment variables.

Note that **timedatectl** for both give similar results, the only difference being that 18.04 is using systemd-timesyncd and 19.10 is using NTP.

18.04

`Local time: Sun 2019-11-10 17:16:18 AEDT
                  Universal time: Sun 2019-11-10 06:16:18 UTC
                        RTC time: Sun 2019-11-10 06:16:18
                       Time zone: Australia/Melbourne (AEDT, +1100)
       System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no`

19.10

`Local time: Sun 2019-11-10 17:16:12 AEDT
           Universal time: Sun 2019-11-10 06:16:12 UTC
                 RTC time: Sun 2019-11-10 06:16:12
                Time zone: Australia/Melbourne (AEDT, +1100)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no`

Comment: The format of the `date` output should come from `/usr/share/i18n/locales/[your location]` (for [your location] check `echo $LC_TIME` or `echo $LANG`). I guess `date_fmt` is what you are searching for. But before changing any system generated file (`locale-gen`), I suggest to use `LC_TIME=en_AU.UTF-8 date` or `LC_TIME=POSIX date` ... Details on 'locale': https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html

Comment: Thanks @LupusE. $LC_TIME is not set on either servers but $LANG is set to `en_US` so that will need to change to en_AU. Further to that, the locale file en_US does not have a `date_fmt` setting on V18.04 but is `date_fmt    "%a %d %b %Y %r %Z"` on V19.10. Looking at en_AU, both versions have `date_fmt    "%a %e %b %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"`

Answer (score 1):

The difference in format appears to be (not tested) caused by /usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US having `date_fmt` set in version 19.10 but not in 18.04. To fix (avoid) the problem, I changed my locale to en_AU.UTF-8.

`sudo vi /etc/locale.gen`
 
and uncommented *en_AU.UTF-8*.

`sudo locale-gen 
sudo update-locale LANG=en_AU.UTF-8
exit`

I did this on both servers and they now report the date in the same format.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I set both servers back to en_US.UTF-8 and both are now report the date in the same format. I am guessing running locale.gen updated something. An observation is date_fmt is the same on both but d_t_fmt is different.